# SQL timeout on last connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a weird issue.  I have a C# application that makes multiple connections to SQL (7 in total).  Everything had been working fine for a while and then all of the sudden, SQL times out on the last connection.  That connection is pretty simple

```
public static void APP()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn7 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn7.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand("sp_proc", conn7);
        cmd7.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn7.Close();
    }
}
```

My connection string looks like this.

```
add name="Connect" connectionString="Data Source=Server; Initial Catalog=DB; User ID=User; Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I am doing a using on each one and I am closing each connection at the end of each class.  Has anyone seen anything like this happen?  Do I have too many connections?

I run each class in order from Main.

Comment: How long does your stored procedure take to execute?  The default timeout is 30 seconds, but you can change that via the `cmd7.CommandTimeout` property. (You can also remove it altogether by setting it to `0`).

Comment: let me increase the timeout and rule that one out

Comment: Better yet - run the procedure directly via SSMS or similar tool and see how long it takes to execute under normal circumstances. Add a little buffer for busy times and use that for your timeout.

Comment: will do that now.  it still timed out from my app with timeout set to 90 seconds

Comment: "There's no way its taking 90 seconds...." is what I told myself.  218 seconds later it finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is timing  out, there are  3 likely scenarios:

- `sp_proc`  is simply taking too  long to run; you'll need to address the code
- there is some kind of locking that is making it impossible to complete (perhaps an open transaction on a competing  SPID that has touched the same data and taken conflicting locks)
- there is some unrelated  server load happening at the  same  time  that is  making it run too  slow (this  is unlikely to  be the  issue  if it happens reliably)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding

`cmd7.CommandTimeout = 6000`

the time out is measured in seconds so put a time out that is acceptable for the users of the application,

I'd recommend this for all your SQL connections too just as a standard this way you should always have sufficient time to get the data.

one thing you might want to do is run a trace \ sql profile on the database that youre running against and also check for locking of some kind.

If this is timing out, I would think that there is a process that is being suspended or a lock of some kind somewhere

Comment: *"the time out is measured in milliseconds ..."* - [no, it isn't.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)  It's measured in *seconds* - setting it to `6000` is giving it a 1 hour 40 minute timeout window.

Comment: @Siyual you are correct, and I have edited my answer accordingly. I forget sometimes what is measured in what